# How to convert cordova apk to html source instead of java

Tags: html, cordova, reverse-engineering

is there any way to convert apk (which was build with cordova) to original html and js?
I know there are some tools that can decompile apk to java or smali, but how about decompile to html and js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the .apk in Android Studio with `Build -> Analyze APK` option, you will see the assets folder and the www folder with all the app content (html, css, javascript, etc)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want

Answer (score 3):

Just rename the file `your_app.apk` to `your_app.zip` and open the zip, all the files are there.

Comment: yeah, i found this few days after I posted the question. I will just give your answer an up vote in case others need a simpler solution